# List MDM configuration and policy as an end user

Tags: macos, mdm

As a user on the end device running macOS and as a part of a troubleshooting, I would like to review the MDM configuration and policy set by the remote administrators.

How can I check what is being managed by [Mobile Device Management (MDM)](https://support.apple.com/en-il/guide/deployment/depc0aadd3fe/web) and what is the policy?

For example, a *screensaver* settings are managed by MDM and the policy demands *Start screensaver when inactive*.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145328/discussion-on-question-by-mr-list-mdm-configuration-and-policy-as-an-end-user); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In System Settings in Ventura, go to the Profiles setting, which will show you what has been configured:

[image]

Within the Profiles pane, you can click on most of the individual Profile icons to dig deeper:

[image]

Comment: any hint on how to do it from the command line?

Comment: The `profiles` command is the only way. https://ss64.com/osx/profiles.html